# which one is more proper to use between anybody ... and somebody

Tags: american-english

Which one is more proper sentence?
1. Do you know anybody who can play the piano?
2. Do you know somebody who can play the piano?

What does it have difference nuance in above each sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*anybody* is unrestricted. Do you know *any person at all* who can play the piano?  The person asking the question  is not referring to any specific person. And the person asking the question is not sure if such a person exists.

*For example:*
Tim: Do you know anybody who can play the piano?
Jenn: Hmm, let me think. No (or Yes)
Tim: (if no) Darn, neither do I.
(if yes) That's great. I didn't know whether you did or not, but since you do, I need to ask him/her a question.

*somebody* refers to an unidentified person that the person asking the question expects exists. That is, the person asking the question suspects (has reason to believe) that you know a person who plays.

*For example:*
Tim: Do you know somebody who can play the piano?
Jenn: No  (or Yes)
Tim: (if no): Oh, I thought you did. I guess I was wrong.
(if yes): Yeah, I thought you did, but I didn't know who it was.

You are walking down a dark, scary street and you hear a noise.

If you are not sure if there is a person in the dark of the street, you ask
*Is anybody here?*

If you suspect there is a person in the dark of the street, you ask
*Is somebody here?*

For a technical discussion that covers some uses, see this at [English Language Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/is-there-a-subtle-difference-between-somebody-and-someone-anybody-and-an)